# Why doesn't QSqlQuery's bindValue() do its job?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a query to get a list of the books from my table, but with "LIKE" operator.

I wanted to bind value to query, but it doesn't work.

Here is my part of code:

```
if(context->db.open())
        {
            QSqlQuery query;
            QString queryString = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE true";

            if(filterModel.bookName->compare(new QString("")))
            {
                queryString.append(" and book_name LIKE :bookName");
                query.bindValue(":bookName",QString("%%1%").arg(*filterModel.bookName));

            }
            query.prepare(queryString);
```

The query runs, but return 0 rows

Here my BookFilterModel

```
using namespace std;
class BookFilterModel
{
    public:
        QString* bookName;
        QString* author;
        float* price;

};
```

Do you know why the bind doesn't work?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: You have to `prepare` first, and `bindValue` second. You are trying to call `bindValue` before `query` has ever seen the string; at that point it has no idea what `":bookName"` means.

Comment: `filterModel.bookName->compare(new QString(""))` is a really odd way to write `!filterModel.bookName->isEmpty()` . If nothing else, it leaks memory.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's almost never necessary to dynamically allocate `QString` instances, and it's almost always a bug to pass `new Foo` as an argument to a function/method call unless you're calling `std::unique_ptr` constructor (in which case you should be using `std::make_unique` instead) and unless that function/method expects a `QObject *` **and** takes ownership of it.
2. The query has to be prepared before binding its values.

Thus:

```
if (context->db.open()) {
    QSqlQuery query;
    QString queryString = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE true";
    bool useBookName = !filterModel.bookName.isEmpty();

    if (useBookName)
        queryString.append(" AND book_name LIKE :bookName");

    query.prepare(queryString);

    if (useBookName)
        query.bindValue(":bookName",QString("%%1%").arg(*filterModel.bookName));
}
```